# Spring data Jpa using new keyword inside select query

Tags: spring-data

I have seen JPQL query like this

```
SELECT new path.to.dto.MyDto(e.id, e.otherProperty) FROM Student e WHERE e.id = ?1
```

can i write something in this way??

```
SELECT new path.to.dto.MyDto(e.id, new path.to.dto.OtherDTO) FROM Student e WHERE e.id = ?1
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should use a query like this:

```
SELECT new path.to.dto.MyDto(e.id, e.otherDtoParam1, e.otherDtoParam2,...) FROM Student e
```

And implement MyDto's constructor like this:

```
public MyDto(Integer id, Object otherDtoParam1, Object otherDtoParam2, ...) {
    this.id = id;
    this.otherDto = new OtherDto(otherDtoParam1, otherDtoParam2, ...)
    ...
}
```